# Adding data using asp.net C# into Google Chart (Scheduler)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, google-visualization

I'm very new to ASP.NET C# and I'm trying to implement Google Chart (Timeline specifically) 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

With data that I'm pulling from a LINQ datasource. I've successfully been able to extract the data via LINQ and now I need to populate the following within the JavaScript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['timeline']}]}"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
  Google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

  var container = document.getElementById('example5.1');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Room' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
['Magnolia Room', 'Beginning JavaScript', new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,13,30,0) ],
['Magnolia Room', 'Intermediate JavaScript', new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,15,30,0) ],
['Magnolia Room', 'Advanced JavaScript', new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,17,30,0) ],
['Willow Room', 'Beginning Google Charts',new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
['Willow Room', 'Intermediate Google Charts',new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0)],
['Willow Room', 'Advanced Google Charts', new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,18,0,0) ]]);

var options = {
timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true }
};

chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}

</script>

<div id="example5.1" style="width: 900px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

I need to populate where you see the room, title, start date and end date with the data I extracted from a LINQ Query. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.